# ASP.NET MVC 6 Update Multiple Tables from One View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I’m coming from an intermediate C++ background (and to a lesser extent, C#) and wanted to try to build a project in Asp.net MVC 6 with EF 7 – not realizing how completely different it is from simple C# forms. I’ve stumbled through and researched a lot but since I’m a total noob I’m stumped at this point.
I have the following models:

```
public class Shift
{
    public int  ShiftId { get; set; }
    //other properties

    public virtual  ICollection<ShiftActivity> ShiftActivity { get; set;}
}

public class ShiftActivity
{
    public int  ShiftActivityID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public int  ShiftID { get; set; }
    public int  ActivityID  { get; set; }
    public int  LocationID { get; set; }

    public virtual  Shift Shift { get; set; }
    public virtual  Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public virtual  Location Location { get; set; }
}
public class Activity
{
    public int  ActivityID { get; set; }
    public string  ActivityName { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<ShiftActivity> ShiftActivity { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public int  LocationID { get; set; }
    public string  LocationName { get; set; }
    public string  LocationAddress { get; set; }
    public int locationZip { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShiftActivity> ShiftActivity { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a shift and be able to input all the required fields all from one view. For instance, when I create the shift, I need to pick the type of location and activity to add to the ShiftActivity table which is then updated. Eventually I would like to be able to dynamically add additional activities (I’m assuming I’ll need javascript for that), but that’s another issue.  I know I need a viewmodel to access all the tables, but I’m unclear as to how the viewmodel should be structured correctly. 
Also, can the ShiftController update the ShiftActivity table directly or do I need to transfer the data somehow to the ShiftAcitivityController when the form is submitted? Either way, can someone point me to an example? Thank you… Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you go to the MVC site and work though some of the tutorials.

Comment: I've read several tuts and examples which have been extremely helpful and have gotten me this far. Unfortunately, they don't clearly explain how to view/update a table that acts as an intermediary table and gets data from multiple other tables.
I'm also a little confused as to what exactly can be done in a viewmodel and how to structure it... Do I just add all the tables as IEnumerables or as a single object... when is it appropriate to do which?